# WebEngine loadContent() не загружаются картинки

Tags: java, javafx, url, jsoup

**Я имею html-файл и много картинок от от него:**

- Html-файл является зашифрованным.
- Картинки не зашифрованы.

В своей программе я считываю, расшифровываю и вывожу текст на экран: `webEngine.loadContent(htmlCode)`.

**Цель:** вывести полноценный html-файл с картинками.

**Проблема:** не отображаются картинки.

**PS:** Html-файл и его картинки находятся за пределами программы.

[image: Расположение моей программы и html-файлов]

**Моё решение, которое не работает как надо:**

Я нашёл библиотеку Jsoup, она парсит html-файлы. С помощью неё, я, в каждый атрибут src="" тега img вставлял разные пути, но что-то не получается:

1. C:\Users\Gomas\Desktop\Новая папка (2)\Lectures\Lectures1\imageXXX.png
2. file:\C:\Users\Gomas\Desktop\Новая папка (2)\Lectures\Lectures1\imageXXX.png

**Код:**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

...
String url = getUrl();
...

String htmlCode = getHtmlCode();
Document document = new Document(htmlCode);

Elements tagsImg = document.getElementsByTag("img");

tagsImg.forEach(tagImg ->{
    String nameImg = tagImg.attr("src");
    tagImg.attr("src", url + nameImg);
});

webEngine.loadContent(String.valueOf(document));
```

**PS:**
Почему не получается? Путь точный, но работать не хочет. Есть идеи?

Comment: не понятен маневр с шифровкой. Почему нельзя в исходном html документе указать пути к картинкам, и после этого зашифровать. В этом случае на выходе, после дешифровки получим "чистый" html, внедрятся в который нет необходимости. Было бы не плохо получить наглядный пример, который можно запустить и посмотреть.

Comment: В html-файле указываются верные пути к изображениям еще до шифровки, суть в том, что когда я передаю расшифрованный html-код в loadContent, то он игнорирует пути к картинкам, считая их неправильными. Эту проблему можно обойти, если мы загружаем webEngine.load(путь к html-файлу), но у нас нет этого файла, у нас есть только расшифрованная "строка" html-кода. Создавать локально этот расшифрованный html-файл по заданию нельзя, да и вообще в этом нет смысла (зачем тогда шифровать?).

Comment: если открыть не зашифрованный html файл через webEngine, картинки отображаются корректно? (возможна ошибка при дешифровке, какие либо символы восстанавливаются некорректно) Пути к файлам (внутри html) пробовали указать как относительные? Учитывали особенности указания пути для java (дублирование слеша, обратный слеш)?

Comment: Расшифровывается все корректно. Я думаю, что тут дело не в путях указанных в html-файле до шифрования, так как html-файл и все изображения лежат в одной папке. Дело в том, что когда мы делаем webEngine.loadContent("строка html-кода"), то наш html-файл становится бесполезным, так как мы передаем не его, а его код. Исходя из этого все пути указанные в src тега img становятся некорректными (если смотреть относительные пути), так как не ясно откуда их брать. Но у меня проблема даже не в относительных путях, а абсолютных, которые почему-то не работают (пути корректные и указаны верно).

Comment: Если открыть не зашифрованый и даже уже расшифрованный html-файл через webEngine.load("путь к html-файлу"), то изображения отображаются. Но если делать через webEngine.loadContent("строка html-кода") , то ни до шифрования, ни после расшифровки изображения не отображаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При условии что в html используются абсолютные пути, ни каких проблем не обнаружено (работает и через `load` и через `loadContent`). Попробуйте соответствовать данному примеру (если это возможно):

C:/Test/Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ниже картинка</h1>
    <img src="file:/C:/Test/test.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        Path pathToPage = Paths.get("C:/Test/Page.html");

        // test load
//        webView.getEngine().load(pathToPage.toUri().toString());

        // test load content
        String content = Files.lines(pathToPage).
                peek(System.out::print).
                collect(Collectors.joining());
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);
    }

}
```

P.S.: контент после дешифровки, так же должен работать.